# How do I continue work on a django project I created with cmd and using sublime text?

Tags: python-3.x, django

How do I continue work on a django project after I switched off my laptop. I'm using sublime text to edit and my command prompt to runserver. I have created a virtual environment and also activate it at the beginning of my work.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your question? It’s hard to tell where the issue lies without knowing what you have tried.

Comment: Okay. I'm trying to create my first Django project. So I switched off my computer while working on it. So which commands do I have to type on my cmd in order to continue working on that same Django project.

Answer (score 0):

First, CD into the directory in your command prompt where your project is.
Second, activate the virtual environment again.
Third, start the dev server.
Fourth, make changes to the code and make cool projects!